# Number of permutations possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Given two permutation of $1, \ldots, N$. Where 3<=N<=1000
Example

For $N=4$

First is $\begin{pmatrix}3& 1& 2& 4\end{pmatrix}$.

Second is $\begin{pmatrix}2& 4& 1& 3\end{pmatrix}$.

Find the number of possible permutations $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ of $1, \ldots, N$ 
such that if we write all three in $3\times N$ matrix, each column must have unique elements.

$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1 & 2 & 4\\
2 & 4 & 1 & 3\\
X_1 & X_2 & X_3 & X_4\end{pmatrix},$

here
$X_1$ can't be 3 or 2,
$X_2$ can't be 1 or 4,
$X_3$ can't be 2 or 1,
$X_4$ cant be 4 or 3,

Answer to above sample is 2
and possible permutation for third row is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}4 & 2 & 3& 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Example 2

First is $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$.

Second is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$.

Anwser is 4.
Possible permutations for third row are $\begin{pmatrix}3&1&4&2\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}3&2&4&1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}4&1&3&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}4&2&3&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: What are you asking us?

Comment: number of possible permutation such of 1...N,such that when this permutation and the given two permutation are written in an 3*N matrix, then each cells in a column has unique and different value ,(for all column)