# Double derangement permutation

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, derangements

Let $[n]$‎ ‌‎be a set with $n$ element‎. ‎A permutation $\sigma$ of the symmetric group $S_n$  is called a derangement of $[n]$ if $\sigma(i)\neq i$ for each $i\in[n]$‎. ‎Suppose that $\theta$ and $\gamma$ are two arbitrary permutations of $S_n$‎. ‎We say that a permutation $\sigma$ is a double derangement with respect to $\theta$ and $\gamma$ if $\sigma(i)\neq \gamma(i)$ and $\sigma(i)\neq \theta(i)$ for each $i\in[n]$ and denoted by $D_n(\gamma,\theta)$. Could you please give explicit formula or recurrence relation for the number of such derangement ($|D_n(\gamma,\theta)|$?

Comment: I assume you mean $D_n(\gamma,\theta)$, rather than $D_n(\sigma,\theta)$?  The variable $\sigma$ is unbound, so it doesn't make much sense in that context.  Also, when you say 'a formula for $D_n(\gamma,\theta)$', do you really mean a formula for  $\lvert D_n(\gamma,\theta)\rvert$?

Comment: Right, I mean $D_n(\gamma, \theta)$. The formula means recurrence relation or the number of such derangement ($|D_n(\gamma,\theta)|$)

Comment: This possibly depends on $\gamma$ and $\theta$. It's basically the problem of counting how many possible third rows of a Latin square there are, given the first two rows.

Comment: Yeah, it will definitely depend on (at minimum) the number of $i$ such that $\gamma(i)=\theta(i)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How the number of such derangement is corresponding of such Latin square? could you please give example?

Comment: By computer counting, the number of double derangements with $n=5$ is either $12,13,16,19,24$ or $44$.  The probability of these numbers is $20/120,24/120,45/120,20/120,10/120$ and $1/120$

Comment: On average, it seems to be $n!/e^2$, but if $\gamma=\theta$, it can be as much as $n!/e$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How can obtain recurrence relation or  explicit formula for this derangment?

Comment: Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527155/) (can't be closed as a duplicate because there's no upvoted or accepted answer).